# Get first and last Column of a Range

Tags: vba

is there a way to get the first and last column of a dynamic range?
I tried things like Target.Columns(,0), but nothings works.

The outcome should give me the the column number of the first cell selected in the worksheet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried things like `Target.Columns(1)`?

Comment: @Gserg thanks for your comment .Target.Columns(1) shows me the content of a cell, not its number...

Comment: `Target.Columns(1)` gives you the column itself. If you see cell contents, that means `Target` was a single cell, and you want `Target.Column`. If `Target` was multiple cells across several columns, you would use `Target.Columns(1).Column`. Please use F2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, for example, `Target` is the dynamic `Range`, if you want the absolute column number of the first column of `Target`, you could achieve this by:

```
Target.Columns(1).Column
```

The above will return the absolute column number, if you'd like to get the column letter, you could achieve it by:

```
Split(Target.Columns(1).Address, "$")(1)
```

To get the last column of a defined `Range`, the code below will do:

```
Target.Columns(Target.Columns.Count)
```

And then you could use the above methods to get the column number/letter.